# can we pass a value when we move to next component using this.props.history.push("/next Component")?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, url-routing, react-props

I want to send **Task_id** to the **ShowRecommendation.js** component

```
  recommend = Task_id => {
        this.props.history.push("/ShowRecommendation");
      };
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react-router you can transfer "state"

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/ShowRecommendation',
  state: { taskid: Task_id }
})
```

and at the ShowRecommendation.js componenet you can get the value using

```
console.log(this.props.location.state)
```

Comment if you have more questions

Comment: Glad to help, first time getting accepted solution without upvote hehehehe, comeon hit  that up arrow