# Saving data in from when navigating using react routers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux

I’m trying to create multiple pages with forms. When I navigate from one page to another, I want the data that was filled by the user to be saved automatically (lets says, in the state of that component). Note the user has not submitted anything yet, nor there is any save button to fire any function.

The user has simply jumped from one page with form components(eg:  ) to another page with other form components using react routers... And I want whatever the user entered saved automatically.

Can that be done? When the user goes back to the previous page, the user can pick up where he left off?
So in this example, when the user goes back to the previous page(using react routers) the component did not reset or refresh itself, and whatever was entered; the user would not have to enter again, hence picking up where he left off. There were talk about using iframes, but I'm not sure about that.

Of course all this eventually will go to the redux store. But I’m trying to solve the “saved” state of these form even after navigating to other components/pages using react routers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, you can take a look at ***redux***.

If you don't want to use redux i will link my answer that uses react-router =>

With react-router, you can transfer "state"

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/ShowRecommendation',
  state: { taskid: Task_id }
})
```

and at the ShowRecommendation.js componenet you can get the value using

```
console.log(this.props.location.state)
```

[can we pass a value when we move to next component using this.props.history.push("/next Component")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095211/can-we-pass-a-value-when-we-move-to-next-component-using-this-props-history-push/59095283#59095283)

Comment: interesting appraoch, never tired it before. thank you for the answer. I will look into this in more detail.

Comment: certainly... when i try your answer tomorrow and see if it worked for me :) 
again thank you sir